# How to draw triangle wave using ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, .net, zedgraph

How to draw triangle wave (symmetrical) using [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)?

[alt text http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/8482/okr20troj.jpg](http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/8482/okr20troj.jpg)

Preferably with option to adjust period and amplitude.

//Edit: the function has to be [related/based on]? x (x-axis).

Something like this:

```
for (x = 0; x <= 10; x += .005)
{
   if (Math.Sin(x * (2 * Math.PI / period)) >= 0)
      y = amplitude;
   else
      y = -amplitude;
   originalList.Add(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double amplitude = 1.7;
                double period = 2;
                PointPairList ppl = new PointPairList();
                double y=0;
                for (double x = 0; x <= 10; x += .005)
                {
                    double p = (x % (period)) / period ;
                    if (p >= 0 && p <= 0.25)
                        y = 4 * p * amplitude;
                    if (p > 0.25 && p < 0.5)
                        y = amplitude - (p - 0.25) * 4 * amplitude;
                    if(p>0.5 && p<=0.75)
                        y = - 4 * (p-0.5) * amplitude;
                    if(p>0.75 && p<=1)
                        y = - (amplitude - (p - 0.75) * 4 * amplitude);
                    ppl.Add(x,y);
                }

                var line = zg1.MasterPane[0].AddCurve("", ppl, Color.Blue);
                line.Symbol.IsVisible = false;
                zg1.AxisChange();
                zg1.Refresh();
```

Comment: tx, but i forgot to add one requirement (now added)

Comment: well, technically, what I wrote is "based on x axis". What is the difference? Just replace "i" with "x" and that's all.
And second thing - the procedure you have written is generating values for square wave, not the triangle wave. 
But OK, I will change the code...